# Opening the selected item in android listview (it's image or text file)

Tags: android, android-listview, android-image, android-file

I want to open a selected item in Android listview. If it was an image, I want to show it, if it was a text file then I want to open it, but my code doesn't work , here is 
oncreate method

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ListView lv;
        ArrayList<String> FilesInFolder = GetFiles("/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/", true);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.filelist);

        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, FilesInFolder));

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {
                // Clicking on items
                String name_of_file =       lv.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/", name_of_file);
                myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
                try {
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                    finish();
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: What's the error/bug?

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a real question. What error are you getting? LogCat output?

Comment: when pressing the item it doesn't open it and no errors appears

Comment: add a Log method to the OnItemClickListener and check if clicks are detected

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your startIntent triggers the ActivityNotFoundException exception...

Have you added MainActivity in your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: yes i added it 
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.readfiles.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

Comment: Just one activity in your application? Then this means that using "new Intent(v.getContext(), MainActivity.class);" your activity is creating a new copy of itself: are you sure that your code isn't actually working but just aren't noticing? Have you tried putting a Log.d in the onCreate method to see if your new activity is actually created?